# \npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: installation, npm, visual-studio-cordova

Installed the Hybrid-App CTP.  Downloaded the Backbone sample.  Set my build to Windows phone and Emulator 720 P and tried to build.  I get this error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BackboneTodo, Configuration: Debug Windows Phone ------

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(90,5): warning : The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation, so it will skip compiling.
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.29 (x64) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\n4ltjwgz.cbl\packages\vs-mda
1>  '"C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
1>  operable program or batch file.
1>C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets(68,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli" build --platform "Windows Phone" --configuration "Debug" --projectDir . --projectName "BackboneTodo" --buildServerUrl "" --buildTarget "PhoneEmulator720P"" exited with code 9009.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The `vs-cli` does not exist in my `\npm\node_modules\vs-mda` directory. I tried to repair the CTP install with no luck.

Any other ideas on how to get this installed correctly?

Comment: do you have the right SDKs installed? To verify these are installed, open Control Panel -> Add Remove Programs -> Visual Studio 2013, choose "Change" and "Modify" then check the packages: Tools for maintaining Store apps for Win 8 and Windows Phone 8.0 SDK.

Comment: alternately, does your username "<me>" have spaces?

Comment: If anyone is having these problems try the following which helped me.

1) Remove the CTP - Takes forever
2) Remove node.js
3) Delete users\name\appdata\roaming\npm and users\name\appdata\roaming\npm-cache - note, that if you use other node.js solutions this may not be wise. I don't know.
4) Delete users\appdata\.cordova
5) Re-install CTP
6) Open a sample application and build.  It re-installs npm at this point and the vs-cli.cmd is there.

In my case <me> does not have spaces, and I did have those SDK's installed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you Node installation was old, or corrupted. Try these steps:

1) Remove the CTP (this may take a while)

2) Remove node.js

3) Delete users\name\appdata\roaming\npm and users\name\appdata\roaming\npm-cache

4) Delete users\appdata.cordova

5) Re-install CTP

6) Open a sample application and build

It re-installs npm at this point and the vs-cli.cmd is there. In my case  does not have spaces, and I did have those SDK's installed.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved by removing `C:\Users\Miquel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\node_modules\*.*` and `C:\Users\Miquel\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\*.*`

Then in cmd I went to `C:\Users\Miquel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda` and ran:

```
npm install
```