# Not able to build Cordova BLANK APP in visual studio2013

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I have just installed tools for cordova , but its not building ... added a blank app project and hit build

getting the following errors/output

its good if you copy paste the below stuff in notepad to have a better look

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BlankCordovaApp8, Configuration: Debug Android ------ 1>Build started 2/12/2016 5:12:47 PM. 1>Building with tools version "12.0". 1>Target "_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "c:\users\kundran\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp8\BlankCordovaApp8\BlankCordovaApp8.jsproj" (entry point): 1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ( '$(_InvalidConfigurationError)' == 'true' ) was evaluated as ( '' == 'true' ). 1>Task "Warning" skipped, due to false condition; ( '$(_InvalidConfigurationWarning)' == 'true' ) was evaluated as ( '' == 'true' ). 1>Using "Message" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". 1>Task "Message" 1>  Configuration=Debug 1>Done executing task "Message". 1>Task "Message" 1>  Platform=Android 1>Done executing task "Message". 1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(OutDir)' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('$(OutDir)')) was evaluated as ('bin\Android\Debug\' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('bin\Android\Debug\')). 1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)')) was evaluated as ('bld\' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('bld\')). 1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(IntermediateOutputPath)' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('$(IntermediateOutputPath)')) was evaluated as ('bld\Android\Debug\' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('bld\Android\Debug\')). 1>Done building target "_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform" in project "BlankCordovaApp8.jsproj". 1>Target "EntityDeploy" skipped, due to false condition; ('@(EntityDeploy)' != '') was evaluated as ('' != ''). 1>Target "BeforeBuild" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets" from project "c:\users\kundran\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp8\BlankCordovaApp8\BlankCordovaApp8.jsproj" (target "Build" depends on it): 1>Done building target "BeforeBuild" in project "BlankCordovaApp8.jsproj". 1>Target "CoreBuild" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets" from project "c:\users\kundran\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp8\BlankCordovaApp8\BlankCordovaApp8.jsproj" (target "Build" depends on it): 1>Done building target "CoreBuild" in project "BlankCordovaApp8.jsproj". 1>Target "CreateTfsBuildInfoResource" skipped, due to false condition; ( $(AddBuildInfoToAssembly)==true ) was evaluated as ( false==true ). 1>Target "AfterBuild" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets" from project "c:\users\kundran\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp8\BlankCordovaApp8\BlankCordovaApp8.jsproj" (target "Build" depends on it): 1>Done building target "AfterBuild" in project "BlankCordovaApp8.jsproj". 1>Target "BuildOnlySettings" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "c:\users\kundran\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp8\BlankCordovaApp8\BlankCordovaApp8.jsproj" (target "Build" depends on it): 1>Done building target "BuildOnlySettings" in project "BlankCordovaApp8.jsproj". 1>Target "PreComputeCompileTypeScript" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" from project "c:\users\kundran\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp8\BlankCordovaApp8\BlankCordovaApp8.jsproj" (target "CompileTypeScript" depends on it): 1>Using "VsTsc" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\TypeScript.tasks.dll". 1>Task "VsTsc" 1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\tsc.exe  --sourcemap --target ES5  --locale en-US COMPUTE_PATHS_ONLY 1>Done executing task "VsTsc". 1>Using "AssignTargetPath" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". 1>Task "AssignTargetPath" 1>Done executing task "AssignTargetPath". 1>Done building target "PreComputeCompileTypeScript" in project "BlankCordovaApp8.jsproj". 1>Target "CompileTypeScript" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" from project "c:\users\kundran\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp8\BlankCordovaApp8\BlankCordovaApp8.jsproj" (target "BuildRipple" depends on it): 1>Skipping target "CompileTypeScript" because it has no outputs. 1>Though the target has declared its outputs, the output specification only references empty properties and/or empty item lists. 1>Done building target "CompileTypeScript" in project "BlankCordovaApp8.jsproj". 1>Target "PreComputeCompileTypeScript" skipped. Previously built successfully. 1>Target "CompileTypeScript" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" from project "c:\users\kundran\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp8\BlankCordovaApp8\BlankCordovaApp8.jsproj" (target "TrackJsChanges" depends on it): 1>Skipping target "CompileTypeScript" because it has no outputs. 1>Though the target has declared its outputs, the output specification only references empty properties and/or empty item lists. 1>Done building target "CompileTypeScript" in project "BlankCordovaApp8.jsproj". 1>Target "TrackJsChanges" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets" from project "c:\users\kundran\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp8\BlankCordovaApp8\BlankCordovaApp8.jsproj" (target "BuildRipple" depends on it): 1>Task "Message" 1>  GeneratedJavascript= 1>Done executing task "Message". 1>Using "MakeDir" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". 1>Task "MakeDir" 1>  Creating directory "bld\Ripple\Android\Debug". 1>Done executing task "MakeDir". 1>Using "MdaTrackJsChanges" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.dll". 1>Task "MdaTrackJsChanges" 1>Done executing task "MdaTrackJsChanges". 1>Task "MdaTrackJsChanges" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(DebuggerFlavor)' != '' AND $(DebuggerFlavor.Substring(0,6)) != 'Ripple') was evaluated as ('RippleNexus' != '' AND Ripple != 'Ripple'). 1>Done building target "TrackJsChanges" in project "BlankCordovaApp8.jsproj". 1>Target "PrepareForRippleRequirements" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets" from project "c:\users\kundran\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp8\BlankCordovaApp8\BlankCordovaApp8.jsproj" (target "BuildRipple" depends on it): 1>Building target "PrepareForRippleRequirements" completely. 1>Output file "bld\Debug\platforms\android\assets\www\config.xml" does not exist. 1>Using "CallTarget" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". 1>Task "CallTarget" 1>Target "EnsureNodeJsRequirementsAreAtCorrectVersion" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets" from project "c:\users\kundran\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp8\BlankCordovaApp8\BlankCordovaApp8.jsproj" (target "PrepareForRippleRequirements" depends on it): 1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ($(MDAPropertiesEvaluated) == 'true' And $(NodeJsDir) == '') was evaluated as (true == 'true' And C:\Program Files\nodejs\ == ''). 1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ($(MDAPropertiesEvaluated) == 'true' And $(MDAVsixDir) == '') was evaluated as (true == 'true' And C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\KRNXWMFK.0J3
== ''). 1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ($(MDAPropertiesEvaluated) == '' And $(NodeJsDir) == '') was evaluated as (true == '' And C:\Program Files\nodejs\ == ''). 1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ($(MDAPropertiesEvaluated) == '' And $(MDAVsixDir) == '') was evaluated as (true == '' And C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\KRNXWMFK.0J3
== ''). 1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; (!Exists('$(NodeJsDir)') Or !Exists('$(NodeJsDir)\node.exe')) was evaluated as (!Exists('C:\Program Files\nodejs\') Or !Exists('C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe')). 1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; (!Exists('$(MDAVsixDir)') Or !Exists('$(MDAVsixDir)\packages\vs-mda')) was evaluated as (!Exists('C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO
12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\KRNXWMFK.0J3') Or !Exists('C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO
12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\KRNXWMFK.0J3\packages\vs-mda')). 1>Task "CallTarget" 1>Target "InstallMDATargets" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets" from project "c:\users\kundran\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp8\BlankCordovaApp8\BlankCordovaApp8.jsproj" (target "EnsureNodeJsRequirementsAreAtCorrectVersion" depends on it): 1>Using "RunMdaTargetsInstall" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.dll". 1>Task "RunMdaTargetsInstall" 1>  c:\users\kundran\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp8\BlankCordovaApp8>call "C:\Program Files\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat  1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 5.4.1 (x64) and npm. 1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO
12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\KRNXWMFK.0J3\packages\vs-mda 1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-mda 1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 0.1.76 1>  ------ Current globally installed version:
0.1.76 1>  ------ Package already installed globally at correct version. 1>Done executing task "RunMdaTargetsInstall". 1>Task "CallTarget" 1>Target "MDACleanAfterInstall" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets" from project "c:\users\kundran\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp8\BlankCordovaApp8\BlankCordovaApp8.jsproj" (target "InstallMDATargets" depends on it): 1>Task "CallTarget" 1>Target "CleanCordovaDeploy" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets" from project "c:\users\kundran\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp8\BlankCordovaApp8\BlankCordovaApp8.jsproj" (target "MDACleanAfterInstall" depends on it): 1>Using "RemoveDir" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". 1>Task "RemoveDir" 1>  Directory "c:\users\kundran\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp8\BlankCordovaApp8\\bld\Debug\platforms\wp8\cordova\lib\CordovaDeploy\CordovaDeploy\bin" doesn't exist. Skipping. 1>Done executing task "RemoveDir". 1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; (@(CordovaDeployDirs) != @(DeletedDirectories)) was evaluated as (c:\users\kundran\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp8\BlankCordovaApp8\\bld\Debug\platforms\wp8\cordova\lib\CordovaDeploy\CordovaDeploy\bin != c:\users\kundran\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp8\BlankCordovaApp8\\bld\Debug\platforms\wp8\cordova\lib\CordovaDeploy\CordovaDeploy\bin). 1>Done building target "CleanCordovaDeploy" in project "BlankCordovaApp8.jsproj". 1>Done executing task "CallTarget". 1>Using "CreateItem" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". 1>Task "CreateItem" 1>Done executing task "CreateItem". 1>Using "Delete" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". 1>Task "Delete" 1>  Deleting file "c:\users\kundran\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp8\BlankCordovaApp8\\bld\Android\Debug\changeList.json". 1>Done executing task "Delete". 1>Task "RemoveDir" skipped, due to false condition; (Exists('%(Identity)')) was evaluated as (Exists('')). 1>Done building target "MDACleanAfterInstall" in project "BlankCordovaApp8.jsproj". 1>Done executing task "CallTarget". 1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ($(MDAInstallErrorCode) != '0' And $(MDAInstallErrorCode) != '-17') was evaluated as (-17 != '0' And -17 != '-17'). 1>Done building target "InstallMDATargets" in project "BlankCordovaApp8.jsproj". 1>Done executing task "CallTarget". 1>Done building target "EnsureNodeJsRequirementsAreAtCorrectVersion" in project "BlankCordovaApp8.jsproj". 1>Done executing task "CallTarget". 1>Using "MdaVsCli" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.dll". 1>Task "MdaVsCli" 1>  C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c " C:\Users\kundran\AppData\Roaming\npm\vs-cli.cmd prepare --platform Android --configuration Debug --projectDir . --projectName BlankCordovaApp8 --npmInstallDir C:\Users\kundran\AppData\Roaming\npm
--language en-US"  1>  'C:\Users\kundran\AppData\Roaming\npm\vs-cli.cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 1>  operable program or batch file. 1>Done executing task "MdaVsCli" -- FAILED. 1>Done building target "PrepareForRippleRequirements" in project "BlankCordovaApp8.jsproj" -- FAILED. 1> 1>Build FAILED. 1> 1>Time Elapsed 00:00:01.99
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed in the latest release of these tools, included as part of Visual Studio 2015. However, if you have to stay on VS 2013, this may be the same issue described in the following post:

[\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398111/npm-node-modules-vs-mda-vs-cli-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-com)

In the answers on that page, here's one that worked for somebody:

> I've solved by removing
>   `C:\Users\yourUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\node_modules\*.*`
>   and `C:\Users\yourUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\*.*`
>
> Then in cmd I went to
>   `C:\Users\Miquel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda` and ran:
>   `npm install`