# Blank Cordova Angular App Fails to build after Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 & 3 - Win7?

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015

I have been trying and trying all sorts of recommendations, etc, but nothing seems to work. A clean install of the Enterprise update 2 package on a clean 64x machine Window 7 Pro (or Enterprise - same result) will still not properly build a blank Cordova project right after New Project creation! It also happens on an update to an existing Visual Studio 2015. I have found that it does work on a clean Windows 10-64 machine.

Is there someway to get it to work on Windows 7? (If that's the problem?). Here's the build result below. First off, why does it try to update npm? I also tried to solve the folder issue, but could not. Again, all well on Win 10.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BlankCordovaApp1, Configuration: Debug Android ------
Third party software is licensed to you by its owner. Microsoft is not responsible for, nor does it grant any licenses to, third party software. Third party software may include dependencies which are governed by additional licenses.
Installing npm 2.14.9. This could take a few minutes...
There was an issue clearing the sandboxed npm folder: Could not find a part of the path '_stream_duplex.js'.
Failed: Access to the path 'C:\Users\ed.chmiel\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\MDA\vs-npm\2.14.9\npm-2.14.9' is denied.
1>  Third party software is licensed to you by its owner. Microsoft is not responsible for, nor does it grant any licenses to, third party software. Third party software may include dependencies which are governed by additional licenses.
1>  Installing npm 2.14.9. This could take a few minutes...
1>  There was an issue clearing the sandboxed npm folder: Could not find a part of the path '_stream_duplex.js'.
1>  Failed: Access to the path 'C:\Users\ed.chmiel\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\MDA\vs-npm\2.14.9\npm-2.14.9' is denied.
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.12.7 (x64) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-tac
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.42
1>  ------ Package already installed globally at correct version.
1>  ------ Installing Cordova tools cordova@6.1.1 for project from npm. This could take a few minutes...
1>  Each package is licensed to you by its owner. Microsoft is not responsible for, nor does it grant any licenses to, third-party packages. Some packages may include dependencies which are governed by additional licenses. Follow the package source (feed) URL to determine any dependencies.
1>  'C:\Users\ed.chmiel\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\MDA\vs-npm\2.14.9\npm.cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
1>  operable program or batch file.
1>  [Error ------ npm install failed. Exit code: 1]
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Build error: ------ npm install failed. Exit code: 1
1>MDAVSCLI : Build error : ------ npm install failed. Exit code: 1
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Update 3, after a Clear Cordova Cache produces the same errors on the Win 7 machine(s).

Also tried latest node, and both npm and node show the latest.

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Ensure you have set nodejs and npm in Path system environment variable. You should be able to execute "npm -version" and "node -v" commands successfully from command prompt. Check out this link as well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398111/npm-node-modules-vs-mda-vs-cli-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-com

Comment: I have done the path, npm 3.9.5, node 6.2.1. Which puzzles me why the npm is trying to install an older version. I have done the instructions in the link too. Please note that npm install fail happens on a fresh Windows 7 (with updates) install also.

Comment: Could you try running visual studio as administrator.

Comment: @user2287494 What the errro you are getting when npm install fails?

Comment: OK, after a gracious bit of help from Microsoft (big call out - THANKS!!!!), turns out the answer is to delete the folder :

C:\Users\<youridhere>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\MDA\vs-npm

The gotcha is that you cannot use Explorer as many of the paths are too long. Use RoboCopy from the developers console instead. Clear your cordova cache, and then all should be well. I was already running admin, and the external node has nothing to do with it - VStudio requires 2.14.9 in its own place. By deleting the folder, it rebuilt it. I must have had something left over.